# How to review changes made by a .patch with quilt in a Debian source package?

Tags: debian, diff, deb, patch, quilt

I've pulled the source package of `luajit` with `apt source luajit` from Debian sid. As the package was unpacked by the same command, I saw the next message:

```
dpkg-source: info: applying 0002-Enable-debugging-symbols-in-the-build.patch
```

Although I did not ask for any patches to be applied automatically, I'd like to review what this patch did, and possibly revert it.

Within the unpacked directory of the source package, the command `what-patch` replied with `quilt`. Since doing it the first time, I've installed quilt (v0.66) from sid, then went to `cd ./debian/patches` and attempted to do:

```
quilt diff -P ./0002-Enable-debugging-symbols-in-the-build.patch
```

to have a clearer picture of what this patch supposed to do in the upstream code; however, quilt strangely replied:

```
Patch ./0002-Enable-debugging-symbols-in-the-build.patch is not in series
```

So I reviewed the `./series` file with `cat ./series` and clearly saw the line:

```
0002-Enable-debugging-symbols-in-the-build.patch
```

mentioned in there along 7 other patches (1 before, and 6 after). So, what is missing? I went to `man quilt` and read the `diff` command says:

> Produces a diff of the specified file(s) in the topmost or specified
>   patch. If no files are specified, all files that are modified are
>   included.

And, the `-P` switch does:

> Create a diff for the specified patch. (Defaults to the topmost patch.)

It seems I can't figure out what's wrong with quilt because I've never done this before and the manpages + the Debian wiki kinda moved past that in their tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a trivial confusion with `quilt diff`'s `-P` and the `[file ...]` at the end of the `quilt diff` command. Apparently the `./` prefix before the filename of the patch breaks quilt's resolution within `./series` when using `-P`, or rather that `-P` doesn't expect `./` at all. Therefore the correct syntax for:

```
quilt diff -P ./0002-Enable-debugging-symbols-in-the-build.patch
```

Is:

```
quilt diff -P 0002-Enable-debugging-symbols-in-the-build.patch
```

Now it shows the diff as expected.